# Unable to pip install MariaDB in Python

Tags: python, mariadb

I've been reading all the other posts somewhat related to this topic but I appear to have a slice of knowledge missing to fully comprehend the full picture.

**Objective**: I need to be able to access a MariaDB database on a remote server from my very simple app (local or in docker) so that I can run a couple of select scripts on the data.

I've opted to use Docker because it's cleaner and less prone to interference from my local OS, but regardless, I get the same errors on both MacOS locally and Linux on Docker.

This is my `Dockerfile` (the app works fine until I try to add MariaDB):

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev

COPY . .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

This is my `requirements.txt` (I don't need Flask but I just want to make sure I can see that pip is able to install something correctly, and it does):

```
Flask==2.0.2
mariadb==1.1.4
```

When I run a docker build, I get this:

```
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt:                                                                 
#11 1.253 Collecting Flask==2.0.2                                                                                            
#11 1.397   Downloading Flask-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)                                                                 
#11 1.441      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 95.2/95.2 kB 4.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00                                    
#11 1.527 Collecting mariadb==1.1.4                                                                                          
#11 1.558   Downloading mariadb-1.1.4.zip (97 kB)
#11 1.568      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 97.4/97.4 kB 32.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#11 1.585   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
#11 1.920   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#11 1.930   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#11 1.930   
#11 1.930   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
#11 1.930   │ exit code: 1
#11 1.930   ╰─> [8 lines of output]
#11 1.930       Traceback (most recent call last):
#11 1.930         File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
#11 1.930         File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
#11 1.930         File "/tmp/pip-install-p7s8jj6d/mariadb_90e5111808594b418ebf9c5df54e9d58/setup.py", line 27, in <module>
#11 1.930           cfg = get_config(options)
#11 1.930         File "/tmp/pip-install-p7s8jj6d/mariadb_90e5111808594b418ebf9c5df54e9d58/mariadb_posix.py", line 64, in get_config
#11 1.930           print('MariaDB Connector/Python requires MariaDB Connector/C '
#11 1.930       TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
#11 1.930       [end of output]
#11 1.930   
#11 1.930   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#11 1.933 error: metadata-generation-failed
#11 1.933 
#11 1.933 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
#11 1.933 ╰─> See above for output.
#11 1.933 
#11 1.933 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
#11 1.933 hint: See above for details.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

Obviously something isn't right with my `MariaDB Connector/C` but I don't understand what.

My understanding is that `apt-get install libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev` should install the right connector but apparently not(?) so when I looked into trying to install a Connector/C manually into the container before running any of the pip commands, I run into the issue that there is so much choice that I don't understand [WHICH connector to download](https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/c/), there are literally hundreds of versions and dozens of files for each, I'm completely lost... what do I need to look for? Where do I need to look? How do I then install?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64309549/9705687) seems to address your issue. They added a repository to their setup and were able to get pip to install the connector.

Comment: Thanks @bfris much appreciated. I wasn't exactly what I needed but it was a huge nudge in the right direction! If you'd like to put this as an answer I'd be happy to select it.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /usr/src/

RUN curl -sS https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup | bash
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install libmariadb-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libmariadb3 -y

COPY . /usr/src/

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "/usr/src/app.py"]
```

The part that I appeared to be missing was the `curl` statement. I had also tested other versions of this from other posts that claimed it was a solution but those failed for me in the same way that my original Dockerfile shown did.

In addition, note the `-y` flags that you may need to include, these are to auto-answer any Yes/No questions that `apt-get install` commands may throw up during the process.

Answer (score -1):

```
I found this on the official website
```

https://mariadb-corporation.github.io/mariadb-connector-python/install.html

```
$ pip3 install mariadb

# or if you downloaded the source package

$ python setup.py build

$ python setup.py install
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't help, I've tried installing `mariadb` but the connector needs to be installed first, which I have tried via `libmariadb3` and `libmariadb-dev` without success. I would try manually but I don't know how to choose a version and the page suggested doesn't explain anything useful in that regard.